# RedActor editor stops working when a CSS reset is used in Asp.net Web Forms

Tags: css, asp.net, webforms, redactor

I am using RedActor Editor in my project, which is using Asp.net Web forms.

In the master page I reset CSS wit a reset CSS file and its works fine.

The problem is that the Editor buttons don't work.  For example,  bold, italic and other buttons don't work.

When I remove the CSS reset file its works fine.

I need the CSS reset file for other parts of the site and can't remove it.  Can anybody offer any help?

anyone how can i Solve it .
I searched on google but I don't found any answer .

Comment: You should try to add some more information about with CSS reset file you are using, which version of WebForms, and that kind of thing.

Comment: can you describ how to do this?

Comment: No, I mean put more information in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem in my project .

If your button (bold,italic,delete,..) doesn't work ,you should delete following attribute in css.reset:

```
font:inherit;
```

and try now.